# cmath is throwing errors C2062, C2059, C2143 and C2447. cmath is included in the vector file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, cmath

I have this old **C++** project I'm compiling.   It wasn't written by me.  I'm attempting to compile it for someone I know.  The code dates way back to the early 1990s, late 1980s, though some of it was still developed circa 2008 or so.  Although I see Visual Studio 2013 was used.  I'm attempting to compile it in VS 2015. Long story short, I'm getting an error where the "**vector**" is included.  In vector "cmath" is included and that's where the errors crop up.  Apparently this code was successfully compiled in earlier versions of Visual Studio, i.e.  2013 or 2010.

This is a large project, so it's hard to present this fully, but **here is the top of the source file where  vector is included:**

```
#ifndef EXPRESSAPPLICATION_H
#define EXPRESSAPPLICATION_H

#pragma warning (disable : 4786)

#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include "ObjList.h"
```

**Here is the error list:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> **Error   C2062** type 'double' unexpected    ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath   17
>
> **Error   C2059** syntax error: ')'   ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath   17
>
> **Error   C2143** syntax error: missing ';' before
> '{'   ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0\VC\include\cmath 18
>
> **Error   C2447** '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath   18
>
> **Error   C2062** type 'float' unexpected ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath   30
>
> **Error   C2059** syntax error: ')'   ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath   30
>
> **Error   C2143** syntax error: missing ';' before
> '{'   ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0\VC\include\cmath 31   Error  C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath   31
>
> **Error   C2062** type 'long double' unexpected   ExpressOffice   C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath 328
>
> **Error   C2059** syntax error: ')'   ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath   328
>
> **Error   C2143** syntax error: missing ';' before
> '{'   ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0\VC\include\cmath 329
>
> **Error   C2447** '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   ExpressOffice   C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath   329

**Here are the lines of code it's complaining about in cmath:**

```
line 17:
_Check_return_ inline double abs(_In_ double _Xx) _NOEXCEPT
    {
    return (_CSTD fabs(_Xx));
    }

line 30:
_Check_return_ inline float abs(_In_ float _Xx) _NOEXCEPT
    {
    return (_CSTD fabsf(_Xx));
    }

line 328:
_Check_return_ inline long double abs(_In_ long double _Xx) _NOEXCEPT
    {
    return (_CSTD fabsl(_Xx));
    }
```

It appears that only the **abs() functions** in cmath are affected.  None of the other math functions are affected.  I'm mystified by this problem.  Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Change `abs` to `std::abs` and `fabs` to `std::fabs`.

Comment: Perhaps `windows.h` defines a macro for `abs`. You could insert something like `#ifdef abs  #undef abs  #endif` after including `windows.h` (in separate lines, of course).

Comment: @chtz If that's the reason, possibly swapping the two includes, i.e. putting `#include <vector>` before `#include <windows.h>`, might help without manual undefs?

Comment: Cannot duplicate with either VS 2015 or 2019, so the problem is somewhere else in the code not posted.

Comment: @chtz -- That was it!  They created two #define abs() macros in separate include files.   I created a "minimal reproducible example" and the error showed up.

Comment: Could you tell me if this issue is solved?  If not, could you provide the minimal reproducible example?  And I am pleased to help you.

Comment: @JohnAlway I usually define `NOMINMAX` before including windows.h it's possible you need to define `NOABS` too... which should prevent that from happening. I'd always suggest `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`.

Answer (score 0):

I got these same errors, and found out the cause was because I had

```
#include <math.h>
```

in a couple of source files, but I also had

```
#include <cmath>
```

in another source file. I changed the `<cmath>` to `<math.h>` and it
fixed the problem.

Comment: OP says he is using C++, so he should use `cmath` instead of `math.h`.

Comment: @John cmath **cannot** be used *instead of* math.h, they are **very different beasts**, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660883/unexpected-behavior-of-absunsigned (read to the end)